# Not sure why program only works once

Tags: java, while-loop, exit

I have an assignment to write a palindrome checker that can loop back into itself and also contains a quit statement. I'm not sure why what I came up with doesn't work. It will work once but then default all answers to "no" and the quit statement doesn't work at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner stdln = new Scanner(System.in);
    String original, oposite = "";  

      System.out.printf("Please enter something to see if it is a palindrome.%nEnter \"q\" to   stop.%n");  
          original = stdln.nextLine();   
    
          
      
      
     while (original !="q")
     {
         int length = original.length();
         
      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )  
         oposite = oposite + original.charAt(i);  
          
         if (original.equals(oposite))  
                 System.out.println("It is a palindrome.");  
              else  
                 System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
                 
        System.out.printf("Please enter a something to see if it is a palindrome.%nEnter \"quit\" to stop.%n");  
          original = stdln.nextLine();`   
                 
}
```

}
}

My thought process was that if the user enters 'q' then the processes would just not work since that is the condition for the while statement. Instead it checks to see if q is a palindrome. The second problem is that once it runs onces, all subsequent entries result in the else statement. I'm really not sure what i am missing.`

Comment: [Java is not JavaScript!](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Re-set oposite at the top of the while loop: `oposite = "";` Otherwise you're adding more and more text to the String each time the loop loops.

Comment: Also, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score 1):

Re-set oposite at the top of the while loop: oposite = ""; Otherwise you're adding more and more text to the String each time the loop loops

Also, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

so,

```
while (!original.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    int length = original.length();
    
    // ****** add this ******
    oposite = "";

    for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )  {
        oposite = oposite + original.charAt(i);  
    }

    if (original.equals(oposite)) {
        System.out.println("It is a palindrome.");  
    } else {
        System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
    }
    System.out.printf("Please enter a something to see if it is a palindrome.%nEnter \"quit\" to stop.%n");  
    original = stdln.nextLine();`   
}
```

Also, it's a good idea to always include curly braces around every code block, even one-liners, to avoid common errors from creeping in.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was driving me mad. I didn't realize oposite would iterate its new value onto a previous one

Comment: @jakemyers: This all means that you need to start learning and doing debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: @jakemyers: also, the your "oposite" variable probably should be spelled "opposite", but this is not a bug but rather a minor quibble.

Comment: For example, you'd see your problem if you just printed out the values of your variables with a simple println statement inside the loop.